# LocalDB not found when deploying to a different machine

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm having a problem switching a project I am working on over to another system. It's an ASP.Net web application and web form wrapped in a single solution, with a SQL .mdf DB file in the project as well. I'd like to be able to zip up the whole thing and move it around, but when trying to debug the solution on the other machine I get an error about the local DB not existing. My connection string in the Web.Config file looks like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-name-of-database.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-name-of-database;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I know I must be making an obvious mistake, but I can't figure out what it is. Any advice, please? Thanks.

Edit: The specific error is:
"The specified LocalDB instance does not exist."

Comment: You are probably not having a latest version of SSMS(SQl Server management Studio).

Comment: Funnily enough, I don't have SSMS at all on the computer I am transferring from, but I do have it, and updated, on the computer I am transferring it to. But I would expect it to all work self contained within VS2013.

Comment: localdb also gets installed as apart of VS2012. So seems with the VS2013, its not installed properly on the new  machine.

Comment: LocalDB requires SQL Server Express, it's not related to Visual Studio. You need to install SQL Server Express on the target machine

Comment: You can also check  connectivity to SQL Server by creating a UDL File.
http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/65525.aspx
Then edit the UDL File you will get the Data Source.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Datasource as below.

```
Data Source=.\;
```

If you are able to connect to your database, then the set the ServerName as DataSource in your connection string.

Make sure you have SSMS installed in your new system.

[Download  SQL Server Express 2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42299)

Comment: This connection string is invalid. `.` will work with a full installation, `.\SqlExpress` with an express installation, and the `(LocalDb)` prefix is *required* from LocalDB

Comment: ./ is a valid DataSource for connection string, it points to the default instance of Sql server in the current machine. More info : http://serverfault.com/questions/430638/is-there-a-specific-name-for-the-dot-slash-shorthand-used-to-log-onto-a

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

[image: DB]

Answer (score 0):

Run the following from your package manager console:

```
SqlLocalDb info
```

If the executable isn’t found, chances are you do not have LocalDb installed in your new machine. You can use the steps mentioned in the below link to debug as to why the connection is not successful to your localDB:
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/15/a-troubleshooting-guide-for-entity-framework-connections-amp-migrations.aspx

Comment: On the old machine, it just returns two lines: "MSSQLLocalDB" and "v11.0." On the new machine, it returns only: "v11.0."